# Why is this NSDate not formatting properly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

At the moment my console reads

```
This is the date: 2013-04-27 00:21:00 +0000
```

However in the UIDatePicker (pick) I am selecting 2013-04-26, NOT 27.

```
-(IBAction)saveList:(id)sender {

    NSDateFormatter *pickerFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [pickerFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
    pickerFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    pick.date = [pickerFormatter dateFromString:dateLabel.text];
    NSLog(@"This is the date: %@", pick.date);

    [ListItemObject saveListItem:[PFUser currentUser] withName:listFieldText withDate:pick.date];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This part is working fine and showing the correct date in the label.

```
-(IBAction)updateDateLabel:(id)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm"];
    dateLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:pick.date];

}
```

Comment: -1 because this question appears again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in console you're seeing `0000` timezone, which means UTC, while your UI works on system default timezone (yours).

This is because debug console uses `description` method, that formats date to UTC, you might want to add something like

```
 NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:pick.date]);
```

so that you're seeing exactly the same thing in UI and console.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can log date using something like:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"Now is %@", [now descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]);
```